# Images in picture box are not shown properly on different PCs - Windows Forms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I created a form with an image inside a picture box.

When I tried to run my application on another pc the image is cut on it's right and bottom.
It happens in several different images and in several different pcs.

here how it looks on my pc:
[image: My PC]

and in my friend's pc:

[image: My Friend's PC]

How do I fix it?

EDIT:

here is the code in the designed that defines the picture box:

```
this.playPictureBox.Image = global::WorkTimer.Properties.Resources.play;
this.playPictureBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(86, 40);
this.playPictureBox.Name = "playPictureBox";
this.playPictureBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(96, 95);
this.playPictureBox.TabIndex = 24;
this.playPictureBox.TabStop = false;
this.playPictureBox.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.playPictureBox_Click);
```

thanks

Comment: Looks like a resolution/dpi issue. Please post your code that defines the form.

Comment: Check the PictureBox.SizeMode property. Right value depends on what you're doing with the image.

Comment: @Adriano The PictureBox.SizeMode property is set to normal. To which value should I change it?

Comment: If image size isn't fixed but PictureBox size is fixed then you may consider to set it to: AutoSize (PictureBox size will grow with image, I guess it's not you need) or **StretchImage** (image will be stretched to fit PictureBox bounds, I guess it's what you're looking for).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `PictureBox.SizeMode` to `AutoSize`